# Insert multi million records into table using JDBC

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

Process looks like this, read fixed length file, run some data quality checks on the record, create java object, then write that object to a table using JDBC. Problem is, it's running very slow. I've tried using a bulk insert, using the saveAll method passing in an ArrayList of my java object, but it doesn't save myself as much time as I was hoping for. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile))) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            int count = 0;
            while (line != null) {
                if (line.startsWith("5")) {
                    if (dataQuality(line)) {
                        Subscription subscription = buildSubscriptionObject(line);
                        insertList.add(subscription);
                        count++;
                        if (count == 1000) {
                            oracleService.loadToTableSubscription(insertList);
                            count = 0;
                            insertList.clear();
                        }
                    } else {
                        logger.info("Data quality check FAILED for record: " + line);
                        oracleService.revertInserts("PSTV_PAY_SRVC_SBSRB_STG",procDt.toString());
                        System.exit(111);
                    }
                }
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            logger.info("Leftover record count is " + insertList.size());
            oracleService.loadToTableSubscription(insertList);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My oracleService object is a @Service that uses my repo implementation to call the saveAll method.

Comment: JDBC's Connection object has something along the lines of `setAutoCommit` (which you set to false), and then manually trigger `#commit` after x updates to do batch processing of updates. Much faster if you're running thousands of updates at once, but even faster for millions would be to simply import the table from a file _on the server_

Comment: @Rogue Hmmm, yes i see what you're saying. i can add that parameter to my config. But how would i trigger commit? I'm confused

Comment: you'd essentially have a loop which would `#update` for whatever amount you want to process at once (your sql server will likely limit you here, make it configurable!). at the end of each loop iteration (and after the loop), #commit changes.

Comment: Do you have to do this using Java/JDBC? Oracle's [SQL loader utility](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm) is designed for this task and will probably perform orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: And even faster than SQL Loader is Oracle's [Data Pump Import](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-D11E340E-14C6-43B8-AB09-6335F0C1F71B)

Comment: Sure, but Data Pump requires Oracle's proprietary file format (produced by the `expdp` utility). OP has a text file as input format.